# Debian - Install cmake from pre-compiled binaries

Tags: cmake, debian

I'm running Debian 8.5 (jessie), but I need cmake 3.5.2 and with apt-get it installed 3.0.2.

So, I downloaded from cmake.org site: `wget https://cmake.org/files/v3.6/cmake-3.6.0-rc2-Linux-x86_64.sh`

When unpacked I got the files

`$ ls -la
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 6 ricardo ricardo 4096 Jun 13 20:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 ricardo ricardo 4096 Jun 13 20:22 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 ricardo ricardo 4096 Apr 15 10:00 bin
drwxr-xr-x 3 ricardo ricardo 4096 Apr 15 10:00 doc
drwxr-xr-x 4 ricardo ricardo 4096 Apr 15 10:00 man
drwxr-xr-x 7 ricardo ricardo 4096 Apr 15 10:00 share`

I didn't find any script, make file, or something like that. So, I copied manually `bin` to `/usr/bin`,
`/man/man1/*` to `/usr/share/man/man1`,
`/man/man7/*` to `/usr/share/man/man7`, and
`/share/cmake-3.5` to `/usr/share/cmake-3.5`

But there is not a script to do this automatically?

On the site https://cmake.org/install/, they talk about a `./bootstrap` script, but it didn't come on the package.

Comment: Probably you confuse the source package and the binary package. The binary does not need to be built a second time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because unrelated to programming

Answer (score 1):

> There are several possible approaches for building CMake from a source tree: If there is no existing CMake installation, a bootstrap script is provided:

Meaning if you got the source tarball, do this. Since you got the binaries you don't need this.

It is however considered bad practice to just copy over installs like this to your `/usr` tree. For one this will interact with updates to the cmake package from debian. Have you tried installing the cmake packages from [sid](https://packages.debian.org/es/sid/cmake)?

Comment: No, I've not tried installing from sid. Thanks for tip.